# Assistance Needed: Troubleshooting Formula for Creating Hyperlinks to Matched Data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I require assistance. I'm using the formula below to retrieve information from a matched column and generate a hyperlink to navigate back to the data. Unfortunately, this formula isn't functioning as expected. I'm hopeful that someone can provide guidance to resolve this issue.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(HYPERLINK("Scheduler!$B$"&MATCH(SMALL(IF($D$3=INT(Scheduler!B:B),Scheduler!B:B,""),ROW(A1)),Scheduler!B:B,0)+2,SMALL(IF($D$3=INT(Scheduler!B:B),Scheduler!B:B,""),ROW(A1))),""))
```

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A17e7tyT1468DUjjjcBUdSTKbChxDOK87-TeTxKov8k/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: "*Unfortunately, this formula isn't functioning as expected.*" Please provide information on what exactly is expected and how the results you are getting differ from that expected outcome.

Comment: I'm attempting to compare the dates in the data sheet with the dates in the formula sheet. After finding a match, I want to use the title from the matching data and create a clickable link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting to generate a link for each of the rows that match the date?

Here's another approach, first I filtered the rows to only those that match the date, and then with the help of BYROW I generated the link. Be aware that you need to put the full address with the correct GID of your tab in order for it to work:

```
=LET(rows,FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(Scheduler!B:B)),Scheduler!B:B=D3),
BYROW(rows,LAMBDA(row,HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A17e7tyT1468DUjjjcBUdSTKbChxDOK87-TeTxKov8k/edit#gid=167925048/range=B"&row,INDIRECT("Scheduler!C"&row)))))
```

[image]